# Посоветуйте версию MS SQL для Win 7 x86 и Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sql-server

Устанавливал много различных версий, но выдавало разные непонятные ошибки. Наверное, неправильно подбирал версии...
В дальнейшем MS SQL мне нужен будет для ASP.NET MVC....

Comment: x84 — это забавно. И неясно: толи x86, толи x64.

Comment: Исправил ошибку.

Comment: мне для работы хватает редакции express, а уж версию сервера смотрите сами.

Comment: А что значит "Посоветуйте версию"? Тем более есть ещё редакции. "Разные непонятные ошибки" — это так конкретно.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov спрашиваю ввиду того, что существует огромное количество версий MS SQL и у каждой свои требования к системе и IDE. Например, в SQL Server 2016 нужен 64 битный процессор.

Comment: @Andrew_Romanuk Отлично, тогда ставьте SQL Server 2014 Express. Но и там ещё есть редакции. Вам придётся в них разбираться.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov хорошо. Попробую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю разницы вообще ни какой ,подбирай нужный драйвер и все. Для Visual Studio 2015 нужен плагин *SQL Server Data Tools*

У меня прекрасно работает, вообще без каких либо надстроек с
*Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2546.0 (X64) 
    Jun  6 2015 00:57:37 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)*